# I am getting this error messsage while trying to use Room database

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-room

ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.arch.core:coretesting:2.1.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Comment: That artifact [exists](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/arch.core/core-testing/2.1.0) in Google's Maven repository. Make sure that you have `google()` in both `repositories` closures in your project's top-level `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 1):

This artifact is failed to resolve because of it's incorrect path. Pay attention with divider

`androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0`